# In PDF, font-face appears to be loading from URL, but is not displayed

Tags: python, django, pdf, weasyprint

My Django app uses WeasyPrint to generate PDFs on demand. I am using WeasyPrint 52.4 and Django 3.2.

I have been using system fonts, which has been working great. Now I'm trying to use local fonts. For now, I'm loading static assets through `localhost`, pointing to Django's static server, so I can watch the requests come in and make sure the right things are being loaded.

Here is how WeasyPrint is being called:

```py
font_config = weasyprint.fonts.FontConfiguration()
css = weasyprint.CSS(url='http://localhost:8000/static/kits/static/report.css', font_config=font_config)
return weasyprint.HTML(
    string='<h1>Hello world</h1>',
    encoding='utf-8',
).write_pdf(
    stylesheets=[css],
    font_config=font_config,
)
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'foobar';
  src: url(http://localhost:8000/static/Oxygen-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'foobar';
  src: url(http://localhost:8000/static/Oxygen-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
  font-weight: 700;
}

:root {
  font-family: 'foobar', sans-serif;
  color: red;
}
```

The text is correctly colored red, so I know the CSS is being loaded. I can see from my server logs that the requests for the fonts are successful, which indicates to me that WeasyPrint is fetching the fonts correctly:

```
2021-04-07 09:57:32,147 INFO    "GET /static/mycss.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5748
2021-04-07 09:57:32,193 INFO    "GET /static/Oxygen-Regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 46440
2021-04-07 09:57:32,200 INFO    "GET /static/Oxygen-Bold.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 47096
```

But the PDF is showing the fallback `sans-serif` font. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try replacing your "@font-face" with an "@import url()" to a google webfont and see if it works?  I have very similar setup, but I get Lato from google.  As soon as I replace it with a copy-pasted local copy of the "@font-face" calls, the font stops working.  Shows up in my NGINX log too, so I'm wondering if there are header issues at play.

Comment: The issue was resolved here: https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1331

Comment: That's useful to know